# Render a razor component in a new browser tab and pass a list of objects to it

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a control that opens a razor component and displays the objects sent to the page after a user clicks a Print button. Using the **IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync()** the blank page opens to a blank component page but the objects are not being captured.
Here is the button onclick event-

```
    public async Task PrintViewableOrderPackingSlips()
    {
        OrdersToPrint = OrdersToPack.Where(o => o.IsOrderVisible).ToList();        

        await IJS.InvokeAsync<object[]>("open", "/PrintPackingSlip", "_blank", new object[]{ OrdersToPrint });   


    }
```

That invokes this razor component page

```
@layout Blazing_Fruit.Pages.BlankLayout

@page "/PrintPackingSlip"


<body onload="window.print()">

    <Div>print page</Div>  
          

</body>


@code{


    [Parameter]
    public JsonContent orders { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<UnshippedOrder> value { get; set; }

    
}
```

Obviously I'm not capturing the object passed over because I get this error in the originating page

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cyclic object value

and this error in the new component window

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Found malformed component comment at Blazor:{"sequence":0,"type":"server","prerenderId":"aa8c4268d131416eb85784e2fcf8549f","descriptor":

How can I pass my list of objects to the new component?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the library [Blazored.LocalStorage](https://blazored.github.io/LocalStorage/) to store the data and IJSRuntime to open a new blank window in another tab then on my blank page get the data.

```
@inject ILocalStorageService localStorage;

public async Task PrintViewableOrderPackingSlips()
{
    await localStorage.SetItemAsync("orderList", ordersToPrint);

    await IJS.InvokeVoidAsync("window.open", new[] {"/PrintPackingSlip", "_blank"}); 


}
```

Then in the page I want the data..

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{


    if (firstRender)
    {
        var stringResults = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("orderList");


        ordersToPrint = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<UnshippedOrder>>(stringResults).ToList();

        StateHasChanged();

        await localStorage.RemoveItemAsync("orderList");
    }
        
}
```

Now the only problem with local storage is it's limited to 5mb and depending on the size of my List that I am sending it will not render. So I'm guessing IndexedDb is the option for me instead.